# What's the best way to convert a SQL glob style pattern into a regex on android

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm doing some hacking on a T9 style dialler for android. The code works by setting a glob pattern up based on the numeric keys which is eventually passed down to the contact resolver. For example the keypad sequence gives the (simplified for example) pattern of:

[JKL][DEF][DEF]

This works fine. However I'd also like to highlight the letters that were matched in the UI. I've been trying to do this with the following code:

```
String filter = createFilter(pattern);
String filterAsRegex = filter.replaceAll("\\[", "[\\\\Q").replaceAll("\\]", "\\\\E]{1}");
Log.i("nextMatch", "using filter: "+filter+" to a regex: " + filterAsRegex);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(filterAsRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(n);
if (m.find()) {
    result[0] = n.indexOf(m.group());
} else {
    Log.i("nextMatch", "no matches :-(");
}
```

The idea being to convert the glob string to a regex, in this case:

```
[JKL]{1}[DEF]{1}[DEF]{1}
```

However I'm having trouble getting this to work. It seems to be OK for a single sequence but not for anything longer. It might also be being confused by the UTF-8 encoded characters in the sequence. The sequence for 5 is actually:

```
"[5JKL\u0134\u0135\u01f0\u0136\u0137\u01e8\u01e9\u1e30\u1e31\u1e32\u1e33\u1e34\u1e35\u212a\u0139\u013a\u013b\u013c\u013d\u013e\u1e36\u1e37\u1e38\u1e39\u1e3a\u1e3b\u1e3c\u1e3d]"
```

To account for all the variants of names with accents and the like. This is why I added the /Q and /E escaping to make sure it was all handled. Is there an easier way to achieve this in Android's java?

Comment: The code in context can be seen here: https://github.com/stsquad/mydialler/blob/master/src/com/bennee/mydialler/MyDialler.java#L976

Comment: Can't you use Pattern.quote(  ); to escape your UTF8 characters and accent marks and other punctuation into a RegEx matchable string?

Comment: @LastCoder: sadly not as it would quote the []'s as well which are part of the glob character class specifier. I suspect I'm just going to have to refactor the code so the classes are more easily shared between the routines.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not averse to using a good old Apache project you could always include [ORO](http://attic.apache.org/projects/jakarta-oro.html) in your application (it's Apache licensed as usual). Its unfortunately in the attic nowadays, but the 2.0.x release is stable and works just fine on Android without any additional crud.

```
    GlobCompiler gc = new GlobCompiler();
    try {
        Perl5Pattern pattern = (Perl5Pattern) gc.compile("[JKL][DEF][DEF]");
        Perl5Matcher matcher = new Perl5Matcher();
        String straw = "JEEVES";
        if (matcher.matchesPrefix(straw, pattern)) {
            MatchResult res = matcher.getMatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < res.groups(); i++) {
                String s = straw.substring(res.beginOffset(i), res.endOffset(i));
                // 's' now contains a the match of group #i
            }
        } else {
            // No match
        }
    } catch (MalformedPatternException e) {
        // Oh noes
    }
```

Comment: What does using ORO gain me (apart from additional dependencies) over Java's built in regex handling? I assume I should be able to get the java.util.regex stuff working.

Comment: The comment on the ORO pages reads "ORO users are encouraged to use similar features in newer Java versions, where available." which seems to imply everything should be possible with pure java. However I shall have a go with it and see how well it works with the extended UTF-8 matches.